# Chart.js with JSON empty

Tags: javascript, json, web, chart.js

I'm having problems using readings from my json file to fill in the chart. I found a function from here that allows me to pass the api url and returns the JSON data and that works, I then decided to loop through the JSON array adding each reading in an array and then passing that array into the chart function but when I load the page the chart is empty, here is the code `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <script src="Chart.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                <div id="result"></div>
                <script> 
            var getJSON = function(url) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('get', url, true);
                xhr.responseType = 'json';
                xhr.onload = function() {
                  var status = xhr.status;
                  if (status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                  } else {
                    reject(status);
                  }
                };
                xhr.send();
              });
            };

            var json = getJSON('http://ec2-54-152-138-146.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/system/listSystems').then(function(data) {
                alert(data.data[0].waterLevel); 

                var chartData =[];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        chartData.push(data.data[i].waterLevel);

                    }
                        alert(chartData);

            var barData = {
                labels: ['Italy', 'UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: '2010 customers #',
                        fillColor: '#382765',
                        data: chartData
                    },
                    {
                        label: '2014 customers #',
                        fillColor: '#7BC225',
                        data: chartData
                    }
                ]
            };

            var context = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(context).Bar(barData)
                result.innerText = data.data; //display the result in an HTML element
            }, 

            function(status) { //error detection....
              alert('Something went wrong.');
            });</script>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is incorrect, look at the stop condition in the for cycle.

You have to use data.data.length instead of data.length:
For reference:

`for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++)`

Comment: What an embarrassing mistake, thank you, is there a reason why json.data.length isn't working? as the data from the api is stored in var json

Comment: I printed the result back from the server and this is what you're getting: 
`Object
{ 
    data: Array[50]
    message: "Request executed successfully"
    status: 200
}`

So, your data array is nested, that's the reason you have to access it from inside your data variable (data in this case being the server response)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++)
```